# Couldn't detect shell config file (zsh - ~/.zshrc)

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, fastlane, zshrc

I have no idea what I am doing here, I am trying to install fastlane via terminal, but I keep getting this error:

> Couldn't detect shell config file (zsh - ~/.zshrc) Please add the
>   following line to your zsh profile: export
>   PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"

My question is how do I locate and add this line to my zsh profile?

I have absolutely no idea what I am doing here.

Comment: Have you tried https://superuser.com/a/886135 and then you can run the export to point the newly created file to that given path.

Comment: can you post `echo $PATH` output

Comment: You're running the zsh shell. Create a zsh profile file in your home directory as: `.zprofile` insert `export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"` Restart your shell or `source .zprofile` to make the changes active.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this line in your bash profile :

> export PATH="$HOME/.fastlane/bin:$PATH"

There are (mainly) two user level files which bash may run when a bash shell starts.

> ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc.

And its depend your OS.

Comment: He's running zsh not bash.